# Не понимаю как работает x += mat[i-len(mat)+1][j]

Tags: python, матрицы

Всем привет, недавно начал изучать [python](/questions/tagged/python), наткнулся на код, связанный с матрицами. Подскажите, как работает `x += mat[i-len(mat)+1][j]`.

---

Код:

```py
mat = []
while True:
    s = input()
    if s == "end":
       break
    row = [int(x) for x in s.split()]
    mat.append(row)
for i in range(len(mat)):
    for j in range(len(mat[i])):
        x = mat[i-1][j]
        x += mat[i-len(mat)+1][j] #<-- i-len(mat)+1,как оно работает
        x += mat[i][j-1]
        x += mat[i][j-len(mat)+1] #<-- j-len(mat)+1,как оно работает
        print(x, end=' ')
    print()
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Работает точно так же, как и ``x += mat[i][j-1]`` в соседней строчке. К ``x`` прибавляется число из ячейки с адресом ``mat[i-len(mat)+1][j]``

Comment: Я понимаю что прибавляется число из ячейки с адресом mat[i-len(mat)+1][j], мне непонятно что находится в этой ячейке, как len работает с mat

Comment: @ZarakiTimkuk Вы не знаете, что делает функция len или что?

Comment: даже если бы я не знал, то что? я прошу ответить на вопрос, а не общаться свысока

Comment: Мы пока не поняли, что именно вас смущает, в ответе вроде многое разъяснено

Answer (score 2):

`mat[i-len(mat)+1][j]`

`len(mat)` -> число элементов в списке `mat`, т.е. фактически число строк
вашей матрицы
`i` в цикле принимает значения
от `0`
до `len(mat) - 1`
значит границы перебора получаются такие:
от `0 - len(mat) + 1`  -> `1 - len(mat)`
до `len(mat) - 1 - len(mat) + 1` -> `0`

Дальше вам останется только прочитать, как работает отрицательная индексация в Питоне. Подсказка - она работает от конца списка к началу. `-1` - это предпоследний элемент.

Но вообще тут явно что-то напутано и могут быть проблемы. Если матрица не квадратная, то тут будет ошибка индекса: `mat[i][j-len(mat)+1]`, правильно так: `mat[i][j-len(mat[i])+1]`, хотя всё-равно не факт, выглядит странновато.